# Is it possible to manipulate and update store data directly in our class or functions without dispatching actions?

Tags: react-native, redux, redux-thunk

I had implemented redux in my react-native application, on button click I had dispatched method in **mapDispatchToProps** and called API in action method directly and updated the store in the reducer with API response and retrieved the data from the redux store in **mapStateToProps**. it works fine.

We can retrieve the data from the redux store in any of our class it works, But Can we update or delete store value in redux directly from our class without dispatching actions in mapDispatchToProps.

Is it possible to manipulate and update store data directly in our class or functions?

Comment: The whole idea behind Redux is a unidirectional data flow which is ensured by modifying global state through actions dispatched to reducer ***exclusively***. If your use case requires (for the reasons that are not really obvious from your post) breaching one of the major principles of Redux, maybe you should consider other state management tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. [The *only* way you can cause state updates in a Redux app is to dispatch actions to the store](https://redux.js.org/introduction/three-principles).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. For that you have to import store in your class like this.

```
import store from ./Filename

//Subscribe your store to get state

store.subscribe(() => console.log(store.getState()))

//dispatch any action from store like following

store.dispatch({ type: 'INCREMENT' })
```

Comment: Just in case you haven't a chance to read the entire original post, there's a line *'...update or delete store value in redux directly from our class **without dispatching actions**'* which seems to contradict with the line in your answer `store.dispatch({ type: 'INCREMENT' })`

Comment: May be you haven't  read the entire post, the line is  **without dispatching actions in mapDispatchToProps**

Comment: Well, if ***dispatching*** action in a bit different manner appears to you as *'...update or delete store value in redux **directly**'*, let it be so.

Comment: I had done like this `store.dispatch({ type: 'SEARCH_SUCCESS' },[ ], false)`
But it shows error in my Reducer.

How can we pass static data along with type to reducer and update store in reducer.

Comment: I am getting the only type in reducer, I am not getting empty array and false value. How can we do so, is it possible to update the store with store.dispatch method?

Comment: You can give key to static array and false value like this `store.dispatch({ type: 'SEARCH_SUCCESS' ,arrayName:[ ],Value:false})`. now you can access array and false like type

Answer (score 0):

Given the pattern follows the reducer state remaining immutable dispatch is the layer intended to guarentee the state would only be replaced in that pattern. Remember the function always returns state if using that state to render changes I don't think going around it will give the intended results. There could also be asynchronous calls which may return stale data if dispatch isn't used. I would think the reducer is simply a function so yes it could probably be changed somehow but odd behavior may happen.

Answer (score 0):

We can directly access and modify store object in the following way

```
import store from './store'

store.dispatch({ payload: JSON.parse(access), type: SET_AUTHENTICATION })
```